# Programmatically copy existing constraints to a new object

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I'm allowing the user to create a new text field when they press a button. I want to programmatically copy the leading and trailing constraints from an existing text field. My code:

```
 @IBAction func addAnotherTextField(sender: AnyObject) {



    let newTextField = UITextField.init(frame: CGRectMake(20, positionY, self.view.frame.size.width-40, 30))
    newTextField.delegate = self
    newTextField.tag = fieldCount
    newTextField.placeholder = "You created this!"
    newTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect

    newTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nameTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nameTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    newTextField.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)
    newTextField.addConstraint(trailingConstraint)

    view.addSubview(newTextField)


    fieldCount++
    positionY = positionY + 15 + newTextField.frame.size.height



}
```

}

Unfortunately, the above code crashes at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to addSubView, only then to add the constraints.
You can't connect constraints between UIViews that are not related...

From the docs:

> **Discussion:**
>   The constraint must involve only views that are within scope of the receiving view. Specifically, any views involved must be either the receiving view itself, or a subview of the receiving view. Constraints that are added to a view are said to be held by that view. The coordinate system used when evaluating the constraint is the coordinate system of the view that holds the constraint.